# How to load directive in ui-router using $ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've seen similar questions but no solution seems to work for me.

I'm trying to lazy load directives in  ui-router. The idea is that the template would be something like "<my-directive></my-directive>" and I'm using resolve to load the JS for the directive.

Looking around and reading the documentation this is what I got so far.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     var lazyDeferred = {};

     $stateProvider.state('app',{
        url: '/app/:id/:directive',
        templateProvider: function() { return lazyDeferred.promise; },
        resolve: {
            load: ['$ocLazyLoad','$q','$http','$stateParams','$compile', function($ocLazyLoad, $q, $http,$stateParams,$compile) {
                lazyDeferred = $q.defer();
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('/directives/calculator.js').then(function() {
                    var template = "<"+$stateParams.directive+"></"+$stateParams.directive+">";
                    return lazyDeferred.resolve(template);
                });

            }]
        }

    });
```

});

The JS is loaded correctly and the directive's tag is correctly added to ng-view but I cannot see any result. I tried to use compile but it's not working either.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

1. config your app as:

   app.config(function($compileProvider) {
      app.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
   });
2. define your directive as

   app.compileProvider.directive('directiveName',........)

I'm not very happy with this because I didn't see anyone mentioning this solution! Any comment?